# Vuetify Flex CSS to add a picture to the bottom? Maybe using v-footer or something else?

Tags: css, vuejs2, vuetify.js, css-position

I'm currently building a website with vuetify. I'd like to add a little picture in the bottom of the `v-navigation-drawer`. The code i wrote is the following:

```
<v-navigation-drawer
        v-model="drawer"
        absolute
        temporary
      >
        <v-list
          nav
          dense
        >
          
          <v-subheader @click="$router.push('/dashboard')"> Website</v-subheader>
          <v-list-item-group
            v-model="group"
            active-class="deep-purple--text text--accent-4"
          >
            <v-list-item @click="$router.push('/dashboard')">
              <v-list-item-icon>
              <v-icon>mdi-home</v-icon>
              </v-list-item-icon>
              <v-list-item-title>Home</v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item>
            <v-divider></v-divider>
            <v-list-item @click="$router.push('/1')">
              <v-list-item-icon>
              <v-icon>mdi-counter</v-icon>
              </v-list-item-icon>
              <v-list-item-title>1</v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item>
            <v-divider></v-divider>
            <v-list-item @click="$router.push('/2')">
              <v-list-item-icon>
                <v-icon>mdi-soccer</v-icon>
              </v-list-item-icon>
              <v-list-item-title>2</v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item>
            <v-divider></v-divider>
            <v-list-item @click="$router.push('/3')">
              <v-list-item-icon>
                <v-icon>mdi-summit</v-icon>
              </v-list-item-icon>
              <v-list-item-title>3</v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item>
            <v-divider></v-divider>
            <v-list-item @click="$router.push('/4')">
              <v-list-item-icon>
              <v-icon>mdi-information</v-icon>
              </v-list-item-icon>
              <v-list-item-title>4</v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item>
          </v-list-item-group>
        </v-list>
      </v-navigation-drawer>
```

I'd like to put a picture on the bottom of the navigation drawer. But nothing seem to work, the picture is always in the top under the `v-list`. I tried using a grid, but then I had some problem with the grid because then the picture was on the right of the grid. Can you help me?

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Check this codesandbox I made, I'm using the same codesanbox from my previous answer: https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-70836234-11sck?file=/src/App.vue

You can place an image at the bottom of your `v-navigation-drawer` just by playing a bit with the CSS.

I added a div under your `v-list` inside the navigation drawer, I set the `position: absolute`, to be able to position it freely in the drawer, set the `bottom: 10px` to move it all the way to the bottom, and set `left: 30%` to align horizontally align it in the drawer.

Inside of it, we have the image. Set it's `z-index: 1` to show the image blow the `v-list` and added `z-index: 3` to the `v-list`  to show the list in front of the image. (This in case you add more items to your navigation drawer). Finally I just decreased the opacity of the image a little bit to don't mess with the posible text show over it.

```html
<div style="position: absolute; bottom: 10px; left:30%;">         
   <img
   alt="Vuetify Logo"
   contain           
   style="z-index: 1; opacity: 40%"
   src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/logos/vuetify-logo-dark.png"
   width="100px"
   />
</div>
```